# Is it possible to have a main title, subtitle, and a UITableViewStyleValue1 style title in a UITableView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

Currently my `tableView` has a primary title and a two line subtitle using this:

```
cell.textLabel.text = [shiftLength objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
cell.detailTextLabel.numberOfLines = 2;
cell.detailTextLabel.text = allDetail;

cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;
```

How do you text on the right side of the cell in place of the accessory type?

I tried placing a label in the accessory view but nothing shows

```
 UILabel *yourLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 10, 300, 20)];
yourLabel.text = @"TEXT:";
[yourLabel setTextColor:[UIColor blackColor]];
[yourLabel setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
[yourLabel setFont:[UIFont fontWithName: @"Trebuchet MS" size: 14.0f]];
[cell.accessoryView addSubview:yourLabel];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could add a UILabel as the cell's `accessoryView`. Or you could just make a custom cell.

```
if (cell == nil) {
    UILabel *yourLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 10, 300, 20)];   
    [yourLabel setTextColor:[UIColor blackColor]];
    [yourLabel setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
    [yourLabel setFont:[UIFont fontWithName: @"Trebuchet MS" size: 14.0f]];
    cell.accessoryView = yourLabel;
}

((UILabel *)cell.accessoryView).text = @"TEXT:";
cell.textLabel.text = [shiftLength objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
cell.detailTextLabel.numberOfLines = 2;
cell.detailTextLabel.text = allDetail;
```

Comment: Check revised question

Comment: @inVINCEable Don't add `yourLabel` as a subview of the `accessoryView`, assign it as the `accessoryView`. The reason why it didn't show up is the `accessoryView` was nil when you tried to add it as a subview.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you to use custom cell and make it accordingly to your requirement, instead of using default cell with its limited styles and different limitation.

Default cell only helpful, when you have to achieve some kind of minimal functionality.

[Here](http://www.appcoda.com/customize-table-view-cells-for-uitableview/) is the good tutorial for making custom cell.

Hope that helps.

Comment: You welCome it will definately helps you.